# Finding values in JSON

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary

What I'm trying to do is find the market value which is under the key "symbol".

With this code I get the error

```
File "C:\Python27\bitcoinAPI", line 9, in getmarket
    for key, value in data.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is the code:

```
def getmarket():
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://bitcoincharts.com/t/markets.json")
    data = json.load(page)
    for key, value in data.items():
        if ["symbol"] == "mtgoxUSD":
            print ["symbol"]
getmarket()
```

I've also tried this

```
for key, value in data.itervalues():
for key, value in data.iteritems():
```

They all say list has no attribute iterwhatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After decoding the json which you specified, the `json.load` method returns a list not a dictionary. The error message refers to the fact that the list `data` does not have an `items` method.

Also, this expression: `["symbol"] == "mtgoxUSD"`, will always return false, since you are comparing a list with a single element (`"symbol"`) with the string `"mtgoxUSD"`.

This code will probably help you:

```
def getmarket():
    page = urllib2.urlopen("http://bitcoincharts.com/t/markets.json")
    data = json.load(page)
    for elem in data:
        if elem['symbol'] == "mtgoxUSD":
            print elem
```

Comment: Ah, perfect thank you so much!  Everywhere I looked said python loads it as a dictionary.  So that's why I thought it was.  Thanks.

Comment: how can I tell between a list and dictionary?

Comment: Shit sorry I have another question....

Why is
    if elem['symbol']
different from just
    if['symbol']
?

Comment: The type of python object which json.load returns depends on the json itself. If the json describes an array of json objects (as it does in this case), then the python object returned will be a list of dictionaries. To answer your second question, elem['symbol'] will get the value associated with the key 'symbol' in the dictionary elem. Whereas ['symbol'] just describes a list with a single element.